# mongodb aggregate problem get last n documents for each stock and then add a value

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

Here is an example of my database

```
{
    ticker : "AAPL",
    date : ISODate("2016-10-18 08:00.000"),
    value : 120,
},
{
    ticker : "MSFT",
    date : ISODate("2016-10-18 08:00.000"),
    value : 50,
},
{
    ticker : "AAPL",
    date : ISODate("2016-12-18 08:00.000"),
    value : 160,
},
{
    ticker : "MSFT",
    date : ISODate("2017-10-18 08:00.000"),
    value : 40,
}
```

I want to get the last N documents sorted by date for each stock and then add the values together and then divide by how many documents were actually available for each stock. So lets say we need last 10 documents but one stock only has one document available then we will simply do value/1, but for other stocks it will be sum(values)/10.

The result needs to be something like this:

```
[{
_id: AAPL
calculation: 1.5
},...
]
```

So far this is the solution I came up with:

```
[
     {
        '$sort': {
            'date': -1, 
            'ticker': 1
        }
    }, {
        '$limit': last_n_docs*total_number_of_stocks
    }, {
        '$group': {
            '_id': 'ticker', 
            'calculation': {
                '$sum': value
            }
        }
    }
    ]
```

The issue with the above approach is

1. This just grabs the last days_needed*total_different_stocks, and doesnt account for the problem that some stocks might not have enough data, so in this case we end up grabbing more days worth of data for some stocks and less days for other stocks
2. The other problem is obviously we dont divide the calculation value by the number of documents that we used.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think it is correct especially for second stage `$limit`.  This will limit the n document after sort which consists multiple stock, but not limit based on the document for each stock. For "but for other stocks it will be sum(values)/10.", the requirement is a bit unclear.

Comment: Exactly @YongShun that is my problem, is there a way to do it correctly?

Comment: @YongShun I basically need to average the data, sum all the values of the documents for each ticker and then divide by the number of documents that we used. Hope that is more clear

Comment: Perhaps something like this? [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0RzaxGfXIuW)

Comment: @YongShun Thank you very much. This is infact a correct working solution. However is this is the most efficient way to solve the problem? It seems like having to read every single document is inefficient